# Subscription Mandatory in iOS application

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, subscription, netflix

I am creating a business model application. I want a subscription to be mandatory while enrollment in the application.I have seen one app  NetFlix doing so.

Can, I do the same process NetFlix had done or apple will reject my app during approval as mention in the guidelines.

3.1.2(a) Permissible uses:  Apps must not force users to rate the app, review the app, download other apps, or other similar actions in order to access functionality, content, or use of the app.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Which part of Apples answer is unclear?

Comment: Just want to know whether apple will approve my app if I forced user do subscription before proceeding further after enrollment(sign up)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Netflix does not have its own subscription page for Apple but it is linked with Apple Id (iTunes Account), so the subscription is paid from the Card linked to your apple id.

[image: Something like this]

Comment: Thanks for your feedback

Comment: Detailed explanation